# Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.01

Tags: differential-equations

I am a newcomer to Mathematica and I am trying to solve this differential equation:

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == -4/3*y[x]/x + 4 a/(3 x^2) + 4/(9 x^3) a  b - 
     8/(9 x^3) c, y[0.01] == 20}, y, {x, 0.01, 10}]
```

I am getting the error message "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.01" and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: `NDSolve` is strictly a numerical solver so it doesn't understand or accept unknown symbolic values like `a,b,c`. If you precede your code with `a=1;b=2;c=3;` you will then see that it understands how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You have three parameters `{a, b, c}`. To use [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) you must assign values to the parameters or you must use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html).

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == -4/3*y[x]/x + 4 a/(3 x^2) + 4/(9 x^3) a b - 
     8/(9 x^3) c, y[0.01] == 20}, y, {x, 0.01, 10}, {a, b, c}]
```

[image]

```
With[{a = 0, b = 0, c = 0},
 Table[y[a, b, c][x] /. s, {x, 0.5, 10, .5}]]

(* {0.108577, 0.0430887, 0.0250943, 0.0170998, 0.0126992, 0.00995869, \
0.00810848, 0.00678605, 0.00579981, 0.00503969, 0.00443827, 0.00395211, \
0.00355206, 0.00321786, 0.00293505, 0.00269305, 0.00248393, 0.00230166, \
0.00214158, 0.00200001} *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[y[a, b, c][x] /. s, {x, 0.01, 10}],
 {{a, 0}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 0}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A general solution can be obtained symbolically for this linear, inhomogeneous ODE.

```
DSolveValue[{y'[x] == -4/3*y[x]/x + 4 a/(3 x^2) + 4/(9 x^3) a b - 8/(9 x^3) c}, y[x], x]

(* (2 (-a b + 2 c + 6 a x))/(3 x^2) + C[1]/x^(4/3) *)
```

where `C[1]` is the constant of integration.

Comment: Include `y[1/100] == 20` to resolve the constant.